# Unable to retrieve data from multi-select “Choice” SharePoint control using listdata.svc

Tags: choice-field, 2019, odata, multiple-values

I'm able to connect to a SharePoint 2019 list using the listdata.svc service.

Problem is, if the control for a column is of the "Choice" variety, with multiple selections allowed, the data stored in it will not be retrieved in the resultant XML when passing the feed URL in a browser.

If the control is something like "Multiple lines of text" the data is available in the XML.

Is this something that needs to be sorted out in the config of the SP list, or do I have to modify the feed URL ?

[image: image of multi-select control]
[image: image of resultant XML]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the below URL, I have added code to expand the Multiselect field.

```
https://YOURSITE/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/prodtest?$expand=Multiselect
```

Comment: Much thanks, the contents of the Multiselect field is now listed. The next step is to use the Feed URL in SSDT, since I need to save the retrieved data into a SQL DB. Wish me luck !

Comment: This link will be helpful for you https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-configure-odata-ssis-connection-for-sharepoint-online/